# react-native fails to build on Android: can't resolve 'hoist-non-react-statics'

Tags: react-native, android-studio, expo

It works on web, but when I try to run it on android, I get this error:

```
Android Bundling failed 1275ms
While trying to resolve module `hoist-non-react-statics` from file `/PROJECTPATH/node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/src/gestureHandlerRootHOC.tsx`, the package `/PROJECTPATH/node_modules/hoist-non-react-statics/package.json` was successfully found. However, this package itself specifies a `main` module field that could not be resolved (`/PROJECTPATH/node_modules/hoist-non-react-statics/dist/hoist-non-react-statics.cjs.js`. Indeed, none of these files exist:

* /PROJECTPATH/node_modules/hoist-non-react-statics/dist/hoist-non-react-statics.cjs.js(.native|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json)
  * /home/esd/Documents/pro/bunnymoney/node_modules/hoist-non-react-statics/dist/hoist-non-react-statics.cjs.js/index(.native|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json)
```

I've also cleared my metro cache (npm start --reset-cache), reinstalled all node modules (deleted node_modules folder and run 'npm install'), and cleared watchman (watchman watch-del-all) Initially, it couldn't find the module, but I installed it I don't know what to do now. Here are my project dependencies:

```
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.6",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.2.5",
    "expo": "~43.0.2",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.13.5",
    "expo-status-bar": "^1.1.0",
    "expo-updates": "~0.10.13",
    "hoist-non-react-statics": "^3.3.2",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.3",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.10.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.2.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.8.0",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.1"
```

Answer (score 1):

Search your project for any imports from "hoist-non-react-statics" - you will most likely find that somewhere along the line your auto import imported `useEffect`, `useState` etc from there instead of from "react" itself.

It doesn't look like you are using typescript, but there was an issue recently with a specific version that was causing this issue.

You don't need "hoist-non-react-statics", so feel free to remove it as a dependency once you are done with the above.