# Am facing this problem each time i run my react native app using expo please i need support

Tags: android, react-native

While trying to resolve module `idb-keyval` from file `C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\Fintech\node_modules\parse\lib\react-native\IndexedDBStorageController.js`, the package `C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\Fintech\node_modules\idb-keyval\package.json` was successfully found. However, this package itself specifies a `main` module field that could not be resolved (`C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\Fintech\node_modules\idb-keyval\dist\compat.cjs`. Indeed, none of these files exist:

- C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\Fintech\node_modules\idb-keyval\dist\compat.cjs(.native|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json)
- C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\Fintech\node_modules\idb-keyval\dist\compat.cjs\index(.native|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json)

Answer (score 2):

You need to modify the `metro.config.js` file.

Add the `cjs` extension in the resolver part

```
module.exports = {
  transformer: {
    getTransformOptions: async () => ({
      transform: {
        experimentalImportSupport: false,
        inlineRequires: true,
      },
    }),
  },
  resolver: {
    sourceExts: ['jsx', 'js', 'ts', 'tsx', 'cjs'],
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have same issue as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70240962/react-native-fails-to-build-on-android-cant-resolve-hoist-non-react-statics#:%7E:text=Search%20your%20project,with%20the%20above.)

you will most likely find that somewhere along the line your auto import imported useEffect, useState etc from there instead of from "react" itself.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow community. If my answer was useful, click the upvote button (▲) to the left of it. If it answered your question, click the checkmark (✓) to accept it. That way others know that you've been (sufficiently) helped. Also, see stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.